# List/tree/Stack - Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, tree, stack

I need to do a project at the college, it needs to use list/tree/stack to perform any task. I was thinking on the Google's algorithm to recognize the phrase while the guy is typing.

Does anyone has this algorithm? Or any other better idea that use list/tree/stack?

Thanks

Comment: If it's your task to come up with a project that uses certain data structures, then the goal of that task is probably that you learn something while doing it. We can't help you learn something. If you have a specific programming related question and can show us what you have tried so far, we'll be glad to help. But in it's current form the question is too vague and open-ended.

Comment: You have a point there... Thanks! But I just wanna read some opinions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Demonstrate [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).

Answer (score 3):

Here you go: http://amjith.blogspot.com/2009/05/algorithm-for-incremental-string-search.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do almost anything with a list/tree/stack.  I wouldn't try the phrase recognition one, though - that'd be a substantial amount of work.  You could do something easy like a phone book / dictionary / etc.

Answer (score 1):

Tree is the buzz-word here.  Implement a tree where the nodes can have an arbitrary number of child nodes.  There's list.  Implement an algorithm that iterates every node in the tree without using recursion.  There's stack.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a suffix tree, just an improvisation of a tree

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree